# How to reuse LINQ Select Expression with arguments

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I write a LINQ query and for Select clause I created an Expression  to reuse it.

My query looks like this

```
 DataContext.Single.Select(SearchSelector).ToList();
```

Where as Search Selector defined as

```
 private Expression<Func<Singles, SearchSingles>> SearchSelector = s =>
    new SearchSingles
    {
    };
```

The above works fine, but what if I want to use two input parameters? How would I invoke it?

```
 private Expression<Func<Singles,string, SearchSingles>> SearchSelector = (s,y) =>
    new SearchSingles
    {
    };
```

Comment: Where is the other parameter suppose to come from?  Have you tried `Select(s => SearchSelector(s,"Your String Here"))`?

Comment: Parameter suppose to come come from method which needed to be use inside expression. The above show syntax error

Comment: Maybe `private Func<string,Expression<Func<Singles,SearchSingles>>> SearchSelector  = y => s => new SearchSingles{};`  and `Select(SearchSelector("Your String Here"))`

Comment: No luck, seems like I can't invoke like a normal function, it says Delegate, method or event expected

Comment: Well I don't work with EF, and I'm out of ideas,  I've up voted you so maybe someone else can help you out.

Comment: @AmmarKhan Juharr's first solution obviously has the problem you mentioned, but his second solution should have no such problem.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than having a field that stores the expression, have a method that creates the expression that you need given a particular string:

```
private static Expression<Func<Singles, SearchSingles>> CreateSearchSelector(
    string foo)
{
    return s =>
        new SearchSingles
        {
            Foo = foo,
        };
}
```

You can then use this method like so:

```
DataContext.Single.Select(CreateSearchSelector("Foo")).ToList();
```

Comment: However, is it not possible with the way I was trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do?, specifically? Servy's answer seems to address your question, but maybe your question isn't clear enough. If you want to do it without a named method, you can apply his approach but without the named method. E.g. `DataContext.Single.Select(((Func<string, Expression<Func<Singles, SearchSingles>>>)(y => s => new SearchSingles { Foo = y }))("Foo")).ToList();` It's just like Servy's answer, but with an anonymous method instead, so I'm not really sure if that's the difference you're trying to solve.

Comment: @AmmarKhan You can create an expression that actually takes to parameters, sure.  You created one in your question just fine.  If you're passing it to something that expects an expression with that signature, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: the 'trick' is that the signature that `Select` is expecting is fixed.  Whatever you do must resolve to a delegate of `Func<Singles, SearchSingles>`.  So however you go about that...

Answer (score 0):

what about leaving the signature alone and passing additional parameters as captured values?  It might have limited use as an initialized member variable, like this, but if you assign from within some worker function, rather than initialize it during class construction you'd have more power.

```
private Func<Singles, SearchSingles> SearchSelector = s =>
    new SearchSingles
    {
         someVal = capturedVariable,
         someOther = s.nonCapturedVar
    };
```

that would work if `capturedVariable` were a static member

or

```
private Func<Singles, SearchSingles> SearchSelector = null;
private void WorkerFunction(string capturedVariable, bool capAgain, bool yetAgain)
{
  SearchSelector = s => {
    bool sample = capAgain;
    if (capturedTestVar)
        sample = yetAgain;
    return new SearchSingles
    {
         someVal = capturedVariable,
         someOther = s.nonCapturedVar,
         availability = sample
    };
  };
};
```

you could have all sorts of fun

***EDIT*** references to Expression removed and clarifications

Comment: statement lambdas cannot be used with expressions.  As for your first option, what variable to you expect to close over from that context?

Comment: yea I glazed over that 'Expression' as I copy/pasted and was just looking into whether it's necessary.  In the first, capturedVariable could be a parameter to a worker member function like 
    `private void DoIt(string capturedVariable) 
    { SearchSelector = s=> new SearchSingles
        {
         someVal = capturedVariable,
         someOther = s.nonCapturedVar
        };
    }`

Comment: It could be that, but that's not what you showed in your answer.  Had you actually shown that, then you'd have a correct answer.  That said you would almost certainly want to have such a method return the expression using that string, not have it assign it to a field.

Comment: I didn't want to limit imagination.  I'll get an edit done after I test the need of the "Expression"