# Moving C# function to expression for use in Entity Framework / SQL Select

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, expression, expression-trees

I have some small C# functions and computed cols from views that I'd like to move to Expressions so that they execute directly against the datasource in native T/SQL.

I can do this inline in the Select, but I'd like to move it to a common function for re-use and testing.

```
var results = context
    .Products
    .Select(p => new StockDto
    {
        Stock = p.GoodStock - p.LiveStock // Real version is more complex.
    });
```

I've tried creating a function that returns an expression but C# attempts to assign the expression instead of the result of the expression and won't compile. Using the following Expression variable does not compile either.

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<DataModel.Product, int>> StockLevel = 
    expr => expr.GoodStock - 10;
```

I'm familiar with using expressions for appending to Where clauses but I can't figure out how to create an Expression that returns a string from a select statement.

I'd like to do this;

```
var results = context
    .Products
    .Select(p => new StockDto
    {
        Stock = StockExpression // StockExpression is written in C#
    });
```

LinqKit seems to be about making predicates (Where clauses) easier to work with, I can't see how to compile an Expression Tree. Is the only way to do this to code a complex expression tree by hand (I'd like to avoid that as it obscures the meaning of the code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) should work for you. You should call `Invoke` to use one expression in another.

You have two options for "expanding" the merged expressions:

You either invoke `AsExpandable` on the `IQueryable` so that it "expands" expressions automatically like this:

```
var results = context
    .Products
    .AsExpandable()
    .Select(p => new StockDto
    {
        Stock = StockLevel.Invoke(p) 
    });
```

Or you expand the expression manually before using it like this:

```
Expression<Func<Product, StockDto>> expression = p => new StockDto
{
    Stock = StockLevel.Invoke(p) 
};

expression = expression.Expand();

var results = context
    .Products
    .Select(expression);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest approach for me as we were already using LinqKit.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question, take a look at this discussion. You don't need extra argument, but the idea how to arrange things together might apply to your case.

[How to reuse LINQ Select Expression with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939027/3728624)

```
private static Expression<Func<Singles, SearchSingles>> CreateSearchSelector()
{
    return s =>
        new SearchSingles
        {
            Foo = foo,
        };
}

// Then use it like this
DataContext.Single.Select(CreateSearchSelector()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Microsoft.Linq.Translations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Linq.Translations). It allows you to define properties with expression trees, and then use them in queries.
For select reuse, indeed LinqKit is your friend, or check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448432/pass-expression-parameter-as-argument-to-another-expression/29471092#29471092) answer, if you really want to understand how it works :)